# How to specifiy my USB cable so there is no risk of fire?

Tags: usb, safety

I am making a USB powered device that draws very little power.

It is powered by a USB 2.0 cable, with the power wires soldered to contacts on the PCB. The cable has to be about 3 meter (10 foot) long.

I would like to sell this device but I would like to be sure it is safe.

I am worried about a short occurring inside my device. For example, I may accidentally connect the two power wires of the USB cable where they are soldered to the board.

What precautions can I take such that the device remains safe in such an event?

Can I specifiy the USB cable in a way such that it remains safe even in the event of a short circuit in the device?

I am especially worried about the USB cable melting and setting the house on fire, but maybe that isn't even the biggest risk.

I would like it to be safe with any typical USB charger that people usually have lying around.

[image: Picture of the cable being connected to the board.]

Comment: Normally you would use a fuse.

Comment: How many USB cables get worn out and shorted out daily all over the globe, yet how many times has the cable melted and started a fire?

Comment: I  can put a fuse on the board, but what if the fault happens before that point, where the cables connect to the board?

Comment: Sell it together with a current limiting power supply. But normally anyway the current limit for USB is 0.5A and that should not melt the USB cable itself.

Comment: If someone damages the cable and wires short out before they enter your device, you can't do anything about that either.

Comment: i doubt 1w/ft is enough power to melt the jacket of  a usb cable, much less start a fire. in this case, a long lead is part of the safety. a small resistor or crowbar could be used as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB chargers are current-limited, and supposed to shut down if short-circuited. It might be fairly hard to start a fire with one even if you were trying.

However, having a device made out of wood and hot glue is a good place to start if you are trying to start a fire. You should use a plastic case; they can be made fairly fire-resistant: https://www.polycase.com/techtalk/plastic-electronic-enclosures/determining-flame-ratings-on-plastic-enclosures.html

You should also use some kind of cable strain relief. You should not rely on solder bearing the weight of the cable, and glue alone is probably not sufficient either.

Normally USB devices have sockets (e.g. micro-B). I think this even might be required to use the USB logo?

Comment: The device must be wooden, that’s part of the value proposition. I could avoid the hot glue but I would need to replace it with something that is safe health-wise… let me know if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Either use a USB socket on the PCB, or some kind of strain relief: https://www.essentracomponents.com/en-gb/news/guides/guide-to-cable-strain-relief-and-protection ; or work out how you can use the case assembly to firmly clamp the insulated part of the cable.